# SQL Update with Inner Join on different databases

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I am trying to update the data in a table with data from another table in a different database with a inner join. The amount of data is pretty big and this results in an execution time of over 10 hours and that makes me think that there is something maybe wrong with my query.

```
UPDATE [Database1]..[Table1]  
SET [Database1]..[Table1].Table1BitValue = 
         CASE 
            WHEN ([Database2]..[Table2].Table2BitValue IS NULL 
                  OR [Database2]..[Table2].Table2BitValue = 0) 
               THEN 0 
               ELSE 1 
         END 
FROM  [Database1]..[Table1]  
INNER JOIN [Database2]..[Table2] ON [Database2]..[Table2].[Table2Id] = [Database1]..[Table1] .[Table1Id]
```

Comment: Do you have execution plan if yes, post it

Comment: I dont actually as it is still running

Comment: Post the index details of both the tables

Comment: it appears that in this case there is no index on Table1BitValue or Table2BitValue

Comment: the id's are indexed in both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try updating table in chunks.
Idea is to avoid locking entire table due to large number of rows

```
DECLARE @maxID INT,
        @startRange INT,
        @endRange INT,
        @batchSize INT; -- keep below 5000 to be safe

SET @batchSize = 2000;
SET @startRange = 0;
SET @endRange = @batchSize;

SET @maxID = 1;
SELECT @maxID = max([Table1Id]) FROM [Database1]..[Table1]    

BEGIN TRY    
  WHILE (@startRange < @maxID)
  BEGIN

  UPDATE [Database1]..[Table1]  
  SET [Database1]..[Table1].Table1BitValue = 
         CASE 
            WHEN ([Database2]..[Table2].Table2BitValue IS NULL 
                  OR [Database2]..[Table2].Table2BitValue = 0) 
               THEN 0 
               ELSE 1 
         END 
   FROM  [Database1]..[Table1]  
   INNER JOIN [Database2]..[Table2] ON [Database2]..[Table2].[Table2Id] = [Database1]..[Table1].[Table1Id]
   WHERE [Database1]..[Table1].[Table1Id] BETWEEN @startRange AND @endRange;

  SET @startRange = @endRange + 1;
  SET @endRange = @endRange + @batchSize;
  END;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 -- Add your code for: RAISERROR();
  RETURN;
END CATCH;
```

This is just idea of chunking, you can modify according to your needs.
Haven't verified, please verify before executing above script

Comment: i will try this tommorow. How i made it now took over 24h and did not finish and I had to cancel it because it got ridiculous.

Comment: it has worked with little modifications, the query finished at around 2h and 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to help the optimizer out a little bit and put a filter on to remote table if possible.  Otherwise it is going to pull back all of the rows in the remote table to satisfy the join.

Here are some other ways to attack it:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pfelatam/2011/09/07/linked-server-behavior-when-used-on-join-clauses/